# JSON result (NSArray): valueForKey doesn't work as expected

Tags: swift, ios8

I have a NSArray as a result of a web service (JSON) request.

If I print `NSLog("%@", jsonResult)` the Array it shows up correctly:

```
(
        {
            text = “Some text”;
            coordinates = “11.333345 - 09.33349”;
        }

        {
            text = “Some text2”;
            coordinates = “11.333345 - 09.33349”;
        }

        {
            text = “Some text3”;
            coordinates = “11.333345 - 09.33349”;
        }

        …
)
```

But If I try to access the value of the key "text" of each entry within the NSArray with my following function, I always get an output like this:

```
Text )r'ì• (instead of "Some text2, 3 ....")
```

So I think there is a mismatch of types, but I don't know how to figure out where the problem is.
In Objective-C it works very well.

```
func getResult(){
        self.webService.getResult({ jsonResult in

            jsonResult!.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({ object, index, stop in
                var txt : NSString = object.valueForKey("text") as NSString
                NSLog("Text %s", txt)

            })

            NSLog("Ready %@", jsonResult!)

        });
    }
```

Any ideas what's going wrong?

**UPDATE 1**

I figured out, that if I just use NSObject instead of NSString it displays the text correct

```
var txt : NSObject = object.valueForKey("text") as NSObject
NSLog("%@", txt)
```

But anyway, I have to cast that NSObject object to NSString or String, to display...

Which encoding is it expecting to display the string...or how to cast this NSObject????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var txt : NSString = object.valueForKey("text") as NSString
NSLog("Text %s", txt)
```

The problem is the `%s` format specifier, which is for C-style strings. You need `%@`, which is for objects.

In Swift, it's recommended to use `println()`, which does away with format strings altogether:

```
var txt : NSString = object.valueForKey("text") as NSString
println("Text \(txt)")
```